# Is there a difference between calculating the dot product for lighting in the fragment shader vs the vertex shader?

Tags: opengl, 3d, shader, lighting

When calculating the lighting value using the equation `float intensity = clamp(dot(normal, light), 0, 1)` (where `light` is the direction of the splotlight), what's the difference between passing the normal to the fragment shader and calculating it there compared to performing the calculation in the vertex shader and passing the result to the fragment shader? I assume calcuating it in the vertex shader is cheaper, but I'm not sure if it effects the result.

Comment: As Colonel Thirty Two already pointed out, calculations which are linear across the whole primitive may be carried out in the VS without changing the overall result. Lighting calculations are seldom linear (and a dot product representing some cosine isn't). However, in the past, the lighting equations have often been carried out per vertex instead of per fragment to reduce calculation costs - but reducing the picture quality. The terms to google for are [Gouraud shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouraud_shading) vs. [Phong Shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_shading).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vertex shader outputs are interpolated linearly (using the triangle's barycentric coordinates) before passing them to the fragment shader.

If your intensity function varies linearly across the triangle, then calculating it in the vertex shader reduces the amount of times it will be computed. However, more advanced lighting equations may not vary linearly across the triangle; in order for them to get accurate results, they will need to be done in the fragment shader (though you may be willing to trade accuracy for performance).

Comment: I completely agree with the main points in this answer, I just don't agree with the "(in this case, it is)" remark. The dot product results in the cosine of the angle between the (normalized) vectors - that;s not exactly linear... In the question it is not given if the normal will vary over the primitive or if it is to be considered perfectly flat. The `light` vector however should be the vector from the surface point in question to the light source, and it should vary for each fragment, unless the light source is infinitely far away, but a directional spotlight would be somewhat unusual.

Comment: @derhass Removed the snippet